# Delay for writing data (if the data is not in the cache)?

Tags: c, caching, cpu-architecture, atomic, cpu-cache

Given the following code which is executed on x86-64 (other architectures do not matter here):

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

_Atomic int x;

void g(int a)
{
    atomic_store_explicit(&x, a, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

The function `g` only writes to `x`, but never reads it. I'm wondering how the CPU behaves regarding caching in this case. Assume that `x` is not in the cache at all and we write a new value to it (but we never read it). Does the application still experience the "load-cache-line" delay in this case, or can the CPU do a fire-and-forget write? The cache-line will still be loaded, but the question is if we pay here some price for the write-only-operation (=the CPU waits until the cache line is loaded)?

Comment: Same as a normal store (that doesn't get optimized away); only the store buffer stalls waiting to load the cache line (with a Read For Ownership).  The store can retire from the ROB (Reorder Buffer).  See also [Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64141366) for more about how store buffers work.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay cool, so it seems there is no additional price paid for writing data and the CPU can continue working without waiting for the cache etc. Thanks:)

Comment: Do keep in mind that the store buffer can fill up.  Especially on x86 CPUs where the store buffer can only commit in program order, so a cache-miss store blocks all later stores from committing and making room in the SB.  But yes, it's the least-bad case, much less bad than a cache-miss load or RMW.